# jqGrid "getGridParam" returns undefined after "addRowData"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I put a new row into the empty grid using this code:

```
grid.jqGrid('addRowData', cnt + 1, data);
```

It works fine, i could see a new row in the grid.
But when i try to get all rows like this:

```
var Rows = grid.jqGrid('getRowData');
```

or like this:

```
var Rows = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
```

anyway, i have **undefined** in my variable.

How could i get RowData including manually added rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Rows.length` to check whether it contain any rows.

and try accessing your data by

```
Rows[0]['columnName']
```

for first row.

Comment: I have tried "Rows.length", but it throws a error: **can't get property 'length' of undefined**. Seems like there is nothing in the grid, but it draw new rows successfully.

Comment: I thought u want to get manually added row , as you can draw new rows ,is there any other rows before adding to it, can you be more specific about your requirement.